# Pricing LIBOR options

Tags: option-pricing

I am trying to price interest rate options with the underlying as LIBOR. What rate do I use for the risk-free rate? Should the risk free rate be the LIBOR rate itself?

Comment: Can you please write out your payoff specifically?

Comment: It looks like a option on Euribor Futures with strike 98.5 and spot 97.145 and the market price of the option is 0.01

Comment: To add, the time to expiry is 0.93 years